# Why RawQuery in SQLite works only without Question Mark (Kotlin)

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

This is the structure and data of my table `funco` inside  database `your.db` (SQLite):

```
Id   Disp  Tp 
 1   Ball  2
 2   Light 1
 3   Sea   4
```

This is my code:

```
var db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(this.filesDir.path + 
          "/your.db",null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)
val c = db.rawQuery("Select Id, Disp, Tp From Funco Where Id<=2;",null)
var stat = c.moveToFirst()
var result=""
while (stat) {
    val mId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Id"))
    val mDisp = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Disp"))
    val mTp = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Tp"))
    result += "$mId $mDisp $mTp | "
    stat = c.moveToNext()
}
c.close()
db.close()
```

The `result` value:

```
 1   Ball  2 | 2   Light 1 |
```

If I replace my second line for

```
val c = db.rawQuery("Select ?, ?, ? From Funco Where  ?<=2;"
             ,arrayOf("Id","Disp","Tp","Id"))
```

There is no error raised, but the cursor is empty!

Why?

**Update:**

The [@tynn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3385212/tynn) answer is right. I think that the documentation is subtle.
I think that compiler shoud be throw an error and not just return empty cursor.

In the same flavor, one can write

```
val c = db.query("funco",arrayOf("Id","Disp","Tp"),"Id<=?",
arrayOf("2"),null,null,null)
```

But below code fails

```
val c = db.query("funco",arrayOf("Id","Disp","Tp"),"?<=?",
    arrayOf("id","2"),null,null,null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) states:

> **selectionArgs**     **String**: You may include ?s in where clause in the query, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs. The values will be bound as Strings.

The question marks are there to bind different values to a precompiled SQL query. This functionality is not suitable for configuring the columns to be used in the query. Your first approach is the correct one. You could make the 2 in it dynamic though:

```
db.rawQuery("Select Id, Disp, Tp From Funco Where Id<=?;", arrayOf("2"))
```

Comment: It's subtle. I hadn't understood the documentation that way.! But it works.